# initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style looks not called

Tags: uitableview, initwithstyle

create a default view controller of `UITableViewController`, in its `.m`, default init method  as below

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}
```

after standard procedure to add data source and delegate methods, correct table view shown on iPhone simulator.

my question is, when trying to add `NSLog(@"did init");` in `if`, like below

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    NSLog(@"did init");
}
return self;
}
```

but run again, `did init` not show on console. even move `NSLog` before or after `if`, neither doesn't work!

What's the problem? Why `initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style` not work?

if using `initWithCoder` as suggested by Michael

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
NSLog(@"init?");
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
if (self) {
    NSLog(@"init done");
}
return self;
}
```

`init?` and `init done` worked and show on console. But a failure as well.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Actually, if deleting `initWithCoder, app is ok.

Codes at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as following,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

NSArray * array = [[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"English"];
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

return cell;
```

Comment: show the code where you call "`initWithStyle`" to set up your table view controller?  or did you put this table view controller into a XIB or storyboard?

Comment: in mainStoryboard, where only one table View controller that's embedded in navigation controller. so `initWithStyle` is in this table  view controller's `.m` file.

Answer (score 3):

"`initWithStyle:`" is what one calls creating a UITableViewController from code.

If you're creating the object from a storyboard, the method that *really* gets called is this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

You'll also get an "`awakeFromNib`" message too.

EDITED to add:

If you're trying to do something with your "`initWithCoder`" method, call "`super`" as well, like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"init?");
    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init done");
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: please see supplement of my question.

Comment: I did. Hopefully this takes care of your issue.